# What will be the range of this mobile jammer circuit?

Tags: rf, power-electronics

[image]

The description on a web suggest that this circuit will give signals till 100 meters. I am very close to the airport so this is not acceptable. The input is only 3V so I feel the website is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That circuit probably won't oscillate, so no worries! What's the purpose of C5? Never saw that before in an emitter-coupled feedback oscillator. And 100k resistor for R2 - is that correct?  Seriously, check the circuit. Or look for another source.

Comment: One source of this circuit appears to be: http://www.electronicshub.org/mobile-jammer-circuit/  It is illegal to jam cell phone frequencies and given the sensitivity to terrorist and criminal activity, you could easily end up behind bars.

Comment: This one seems to be the electronic equivalent of a 6C homeopathic medicine (of course **intent** might figure into what happens to OP).

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit is not acceptable no matter how far you are away from an airport. Jamming is illegal in most parts of this planet.  The range depends on: the battery voltage, the circuit, the antenna coupling, and the exact nature of the antenna.